# Transit visas in Kuwait and London

Tags: usa, study

Is any transit visa needed if I'm flying to USA from India on F1 visa & my flight have stops at Kuwait City (plane change) & London (same plane)?

According to my home work, for Kuwait City: no transit visa is required no matter whether one is changing the plane or not but for London Heathrow: in-transit visa is required only when you’ve to change the plane not in case if you’re continuing on the same plane. Please correct me asap If I’m wrong. Thanks a lot.

P.S Please help me to confirm my understanding of non requirement of in transit visa for Kuwait city. Just for confirmation, I'll be travelling on Kuwait Airways via stops at Kuwait City and London Heathrow. Can anybody give me link to ticket cancellation penalty policy for Kuwait Airways; as I'm unable to google it at my own.

Comment: The UK doesn't require airside transit visa for holders of valid US visas anyway.

Comment: As you are holding a valid US visa and are traveling to the US, you don't have to worry about transit requirements for airside transit in the UK - furthermore, if you are traveling on KU (Kuwait Airways), you don't have to leave the aircraft either.